# How to populate ActiveAssignmentCount for Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleDefinition?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, pim

when I run this command:

```
Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleDefinition -ProviderId aadRoles -ResourceId $global:varTenant.ObjectId | Format-List
```

None of the results have any values for the fields I've outlined in red. For example, roles that I know have active assignments don't show any value in the ActiveAssignmentCount property. How can I get those values to populate?
[image: results of running the above command, showing the empty property values]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

When I execute the commands and got same output like below :

```rb
Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleDefinition -ProviderId aadRoles -ResourceId $global:varTenant.ObjectId | Format-List
```

[image]

- I have checked this [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/powershell-for-azure-ad-roles#retrieving-role-definitions). As per my understand role definition command shows the default value for the **`PIM`**.

You can get the active and eligible assignments by running this command:

```
Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId "< tenant Id >" -Filter "subjectId eq '< User id>'''
```

**Output:**
[image]

Make use of  below scripts to get the Active assignments count and Eligible assignments count.

**Activeassignmentscount:**

To get the specific user for **`Activeassignmentcount`** you can use this script.

```
$Pims= Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId "< Tenant ID>" -Filter "subjectId eq '< User object Id >'"
$count=0
Foreach($pim in $Pims.AssignmentState)
{
If($pim -eq “Active” )
{
$count++
$ActiveAssignmentCount=$count
}
}

Write-Host "ActiveAssignmentCount = " $ActiveAssignmentCount
Write-Host " "
```

***Powershell:***

[image]

**Eligibleassignmentscount:**

To get the specific user for **`Eligibleassignmentcount`** you can use this script.

```
$Pims= Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment -ProviderId "aadRoles" -ResourceId "< Tenantid >" -Filter "subjectId eq 'userid'"
$count=0
Foreach($pim in $Pims.AssignmentState)
{
If($pim -eq “Eligible” )
{
$count++
$EligibleAssignmentCount=$count
}
}Write-Host "EligibleAsssignmentCount = " $EligibleAssignmentCount Write-Host " "
```

[image]

Refer this [link](https://gotoguy.blog/2019/11/22/how-to-use-azure-ad-privileged-identity-management-powershell-and-graph-api/#:%7E:text=for%20Azure%20Resources:-,GET%20/privilegedAccess/azureResources/resources/%7BresourceId%7D/roleDefinitions,-GET%20/privilegedAccess/azureResources) you can also get the process through **`graph explorer`**.

Comment: Much appreciated Venkatesan. I moved on to Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignment yesterday, but was curious to see if there was something simple I was missing.

Your effort in the reply is wonderful and I'll reference it as needed.